# ¿Es posible agregar un LinearLayout en un ConstraintLayout o cualquier otro Layout?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

Agregué un `LinearLayout` en un `ConstraintLayout` y me aparecen los siguientes errores:

[image]

Quisiera saber si lo agregué mal o si no es posible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ¿Es posible agregar un LinearLayout en un ConstraintLayout o cualquier
>   otro Layout?

Es posible agregar cualquier layout usando ConstraintLayout, en realidad ConstraintLayout nos sirve para construir layouts complejos que sean responsivos, es decir que se puedan ver correctamente en  en cualquier tamaño, densidad, etc...

El mensaje que tienes :

> This view is not constrained vertically. At runtime it will jump to
>   the left unless you add a vertical constraint (Esta vista no está restringida verticalmente. En tiempo de ejecución saltará a la izquierda a menos que añada una restricción vertical).

Para evitar este error como ejemplo la siguiente imagen, en tu vista busca el extremo izquierdo y arrastra el punto verde hacia la derecha:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con esto crearas una restricción (Constraint) para que la vista siempre se muestre correctamente horizontalmente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo mismo verticalmente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para obtener las restricciones:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]