# ¿Porque cuando quiero insertar un boton en "Android Studio" me sale ese error?

Tags: android-studio

[image]
Saludos, soy nuevo en el mundo de programar para android y tengo un problemita el cual me impide continuar con mi aprendisaje... el cual es cuando quiero insertar un boton me sale ese error, yo pongo mi boton en una posicion indicada en el creadorde la app Y cuando instalo la app en mi android me manda el boton a la posicion (0,0).

Answer (score 1):

Estas usando un [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html) para contener tus elementos, y el mensaje en realidad indica que cuando ejecutes tu aplicación tu botón o vistas se mostrarían en realidad en la coordenada 0,0 (esquina superior izquierda), para evitar esto debes definir restricciones a tus elementos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Da click en los circulos de los extremos y arrastralos de la vista hacia los extremos del contenedor (arriba, abajo, izquierda y derecha) con esto al ejecutar tu aplicación la posición se mostraría correctamente de acuerdo a las restricciones definidas.

Te recomiendo revises esta respuesta:

[¿Es posible agregar un LinearLayout en un ConstraintLayout o cualquier otro Layout?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/56352/es-posible-agregar-un-linearlayout-en-un-constraintlayout-o-cualquier-otro-layo)