# Me falla android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, c, xml

Ayer android studio me pedia una actualizacion entonces la instale y desde entonces no me quiere funcionar , a la hora de lanzar la aplicacion al emulador los botones o edit text se ponen en la parte superior izquierda juntas[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Puedes editar tu pregunta e incluír tu código xml asociado a esa vista? así te podríamos resolver tu problema y darte algo de información.

Answer (score 2):

No es que no funcione, estas usando [**ConstraintLayout**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout.html) como contenedor principal,

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout ...>
```

tienes que agregar restricciones horizontales y verticales, ve a los bordes de la vista y el circulo verde arrastralo a los extremos.

> Si no agregas estas restricciones, aunque veas en la vista de diseño
>   los botones o vista posicionados correctamente, al iniciar tu aplicación se
>   verán en la posición superior izquierda, coordenadas (0,0) de android.

Debes de tener restricciones en las vistas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

revisa esta pregunta:

[¿Es posible agregar un LinearLayout en un ConstraintLayout o cualquier otro Layout?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/56352/es-posible-agregar-un-linearlayout-en-un-constraintlayout-o-cualquier-otro-layo)

y ve la documentación:

https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html

Comment: voy viendo tu respuesta pero gracias de todas formas si lo logre reparar, estuve checando con proyectos anteriores que tenia y solo le borre el constraint layout y puse Relative Layout

Comment: No es repararlo simplemente se uso otro Layout, cuando uses el soporte para ConstraintLayout y uses un layout debes agregar las restricciones (Constraints) para que se muestre correctamente.

Comment: bueno gracias es que el constraint no se usarlo

Comment: Con la adopcion de distinos tamaños, medidas y densidades de dispositivos, para que se vea correctamente en todos se implemento como en iOS el ConstraintLayout, te recomiendo inicies a revisar, en un futuro serà comun el uso de este layout.