# ¿Como manejar la alineación de elementos View en Constraint Layout?

Tags: android-layout

Al alinear elementos de tipo View de manera gráfica, esta marcando un error el editor XML, de que estos elementos no son de tipo Layout Constrained. 
Android Studio: 2.3.1
¿Como debe manejarse la alineación de elementos bajo este nuevo tipo de Layout?

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.argo.holamundo.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/mensaje"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Escribe tu Dato"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="7dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="145dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/nombre"
        android:layout_width="383dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:hint="Nombre:"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="50dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="1dp" />
    
    <Button
        android:layout_width="88dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="127dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="148dp"
        android:text="Enviar"/>



</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: A que te refieres con "Como debe manejarse la alineación de elementos bajo este nuevo tipo de Layout?" qué es lo que quieres lograr ?, por ejemplo que se comporten como un LinearLayout y esté uno debajo o al lado del otro?, o solo agregar los parámetros necesarios para ConstraintLayout ?. Si es lo segundo, puedes abrir el editor gráfico y la IDE te agrega los campos requeridos.

Comment: que se comporten como Linear elementos hacia abajo, ponerle alineación centrada, tamaños.

Comment: Realiza el ejercicio con un solo elemento, agrega las restricciones horizontales y verticales y ejecuta la aplicación veras que queda en la posicion que define las restricciones. Arrastra las bolitas hacia los extremos.

Comment: de acuerdo, gracia

Answer (score 1):

Como su nombre lo indica, cuando usas [**ConstraintLayout**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout.html) como contenedor principal,

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout ...>
```

tienes que agregar restricciones horizontales y verticales, ve a los bordes de la vista y el circulo verde arrastralo a los extremos.

> Si no agregas estas restricciones, aunque veas en la vista de diseño
>   los botones o vista posicionados correctamente, al iniciar tu aplicación se
>   verán en la posición superior izquierda, coordenadas (0,0) de android.

Debes de tener restricciones en las vistas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

revisa esta pregunta:

[¿Es posible agregar un LinearLayout en un ConstraintLayout o cualquier otro Layout?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/56352/es-posible-agregar-un-linearlayout-en-un-constraintlayout-o-cualquier-otro-layo)

y ve la documentación:

https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html

https://developer.android.com/studio/write/layout-editor.html?hl=es-419

Comment: de acuerdo, gracias