# Android Studio mensaje: Missing Constraints in ConstraintLayout

Tags: java, android-studio

No fue hasta hace poco que aprendí en Java lo necesario para programar aplicaciones en android y soy prácticamente un novato en esta tecnología, me ayudaría mucho si me ayudaran con este mensaje de advertencia.

> Message: This view is not constrained, it only has designtime
>   positions, so it will jump to (0,0) unless you add constraints
>   Suggested Fixes:
>
> - Suppress: Add tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" attribute
>    Priority: 6 / 10 Category: Correctness Severity: Error Explanation:
>   Missing Constraints in ConstraintLayout. The layout editor allows you
>   to place widgets anywhere on the canvas, and it records the current
>   position with designtime attributes (such as layout_editor_absoluteX.)
>   These attributes are not applied at runtime, so if you push your
>   layout on a device, the widgets may appear in a different location
>   than shown in the editor. To fix this, make sure a widget has both
>   horizontal and vertical constraints by dragging from the edge
>   connections.

Haría lo que me dice la advertencia pero no entendería lo que acabo de hacer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Estas usando en soporte para `ConstraintLayout`, si no agregas restricciones, al iniciar tu aplicacion, todas las vistas se moveran a la coordenada 0,0 (vista superior derecha).

Tienes dos opciones:

- Agregas restricciones a tus vistas.
- Cambia en tu layout el `ConstraintLayout` por otro layout por ejemplo `LinearLayout` o `RelativeLayout`.

Revisa estas preguntas relacionadas:

[Elementos amontonados Android Studio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/57616/elementos-amontonados-android-studio/57785#57785)

[¿Es posible agregar un LinearLayout en un ConstraintLayout o cualquier otro Layout?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/56352/es-posible-agregar-un-linearlayout-en-un-constraintlayout-o-cualquier-otro-layo/56937#56937)

[¿Como manejar la alineación de elementos View en Constraint Layout?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/71634/como-manejar-la-alineaci%C3%B3n-de-elementos-view-en-constraint-layout/71636#71636)

---

Acerca del `ConstraintLayout`, te recomiendo leer primeramente 
https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html

Como ejemplo un layot que contiene 2 vistas (botones):

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/Boton1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    android:text="Entrada"
    android:textSize="30sp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/Boton2"
    android:layout_width="147dp"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    android:text="Boton 2"
    android:textSize="30sp" />
```

Posteriormente puedes agregar un margen por ejemplo left (izquierdo) y top (arriba) para posicionar los botones, esto se realiza dando click y arrastrar alguno de los circulos verdes que se encuentra a la izquierda, derecha, arriba y abajo de la vista.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

obtendrías un layout similar a :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.pedro.botones.Botones">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Boton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Boton 1"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="119dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="49dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Boton2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:text="Boton 2"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="119dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="206dp" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Cuando ejecutes tu aplicación podras ver los botones de acuerdo a las posiciones que definiste en los elementos dentro del ConstraintLayout. Es importante leer la teoría y el uso de la herramienta.

Comment: Gracias por tomarte el tiempo en ayudarme, no te imaginas la depresión que tenia por ese problema.

Comment: Hola Cokoro, en realidad no es un problema, es un aviso en el caso de usar ConstraintLayout, si no lo has manejado puedes usar los comunes, pero te recomiendo empezar a practicar su uso porque en un futuro te puede ser de mucha utilidad.