# Error en layout Android studio

Tags: android, android-layout

Estoy haciendo un app en Android pero tengo el problema de que cuando corro el app en mi dispoitivo me tira todos mis objetos en el mismo espacio. Creen saber a que se deba?
Aquí les dejo mi **XML**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.sac_a.owsapp.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnQr"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Vista QR"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="46dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="388dp"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnGps"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="clickGps"
        android:text="Vista Gps"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="253dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="99dp" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Así es como se ve en mi dispositivo
 [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como siempre agradezco infinitamente su ayuda.

Comment: lo que pasa que tienes que borrar el constrain y poner relative layout
ya me a pasado bueno suerte

Comment: Con respecto a la realización de preguntas que estas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas excelentes respuestas, **es muy importante leer [ask]** , saludos!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

lo que pasa que tienes que borrar el constrain y poner relative layout
ya me a pasado bueno suerte

Comment: Gracias esta increible, pero ahora mi telefono se cierra cuando lo ejecuto u.u

Comment: @BrayanEnriqueRamirezPartida esto no parece una respuesta, revisa [answer], me imagino te refieres a ContraintLayout, ¿porque borrarlo si se puede usar?, te sugiero agregues más detalles a tu respuesta porque parece más un comentario, saludos.

Comment: lo super borre y use el relativelayout y todo súper, pero gracias por motivarme a aprender.

Answer (score 1):

> cuando corro el app en mi dispoitivo me tira todos mis objetos en el
>   mismo espacio

Esto se debe que estas utilizando *ConstraintLayout*, para ello tienes que agregar restricciones a cada uno de los elementos que tendrás en tu vista.

**Tutoriales sobre el uso de ConstraintLayout:**

https://developer.android.com/studio/write/layout-editor.html

https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/constraint-layout/index.html#0

**Pregunta respondida, para que tengas una visión del uso de restricciones al utilizar ConstraintLayout:**

[Android Studio mensaje: Missing Constraints in ConstraintLayout](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/82971/android-studio-mensaje-missing-constraints-in-constraintlayout)